# Spark Send DataFrame as body of HTTP Post request

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark

I have a data frame which I want to send it as the body of `HTTP Post` request, what's the best `Sparky` way to do it?
How can I control a number of HTTP requests?
If the number of records gets bigger is there any way to split sending data frame into multiple HTTP Post call?

let's say my data frame is like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|               user_id                |    city    | user_name  |   facebook_id    |
+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------------+
| 55c3c59d-0163-46a2-b495-bc352a8de883 | Toronto    | username_x | 0123482174440907 |
| e2ddv22d-4132-c211-4425-9933aa8de454 | Washington | username_y | 0432982476780234 |
+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

I want to have `user_id` and `facebook_id` in the body of HTTP Post request to this endpoint `localhost:8080/api/spark`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using `foreachPartition` method on a Dataframe. I am assuming here you want to make an Http Call for each row in the Dataframe in parallel. `foreachPartition` operates on each partition of the Dataframe in parallel. If you wanted to batch multiple rows together in a single HTTP post call that too is possible by changing the signature of the `makeHttpCall` method from `Row` to `Iterator[Row]`

```
  def test(): Unit = {
    val df: DataFrame = null
    df.foreachPartition(_.foreach(x => makeHttpCall(x)))
  }

  def makeHttpCall(row: Row) = {
    val json = Json.obj("user_name" -> row.getString(2), "facebook_id" -> row.getString(3))
    /**
      * code make Http call
      */
  }
```

for making bulk Http request `makeHttpCall`. make sure you have sufficient number of partitions in the dataframe so that each partition is small enough to make your Http Post request.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}
import play.api.libs.json.Json

  def test(): Unit = {
    val df: DataFrame = null
    df.foreachPartition(x => makeHttpCall(x))
  }

  def makeHttpCall(row: Iterator[Row]) = {
    val json = Json.arr(row.toSeq.map(x => Json.obj("user_name" -> x.getString(2), "facebook_id" -> x.getString(3))))
    /**
      * code make Http call
      */
  }
```

Comment: I prefer to send a bulk request, and in the body have an array of JSON object

Comment: what's the import for `Json` none of my editor's suggestion works for me

Comment: I was using play json https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/2.5.1. But you can use any scala/java based json library that suites your need.

Comment: Thank, in my code also complain about a signature, `cannot resolve reference makeHttpCall with such signature`, when using your second approach

Comment: try `df.foreachPartition(x => makeHttpCall(x))` updated the answer

Comment: it's weird but the function doesn't work for me, I even tried to put some `println` in the function but it doesn't do anything
  def makeHttpCall(row: Iterator[Row]) = {
    //    val json = Json.arr(row.toSeq.map(x => Json.obj("user_name" -> x.getString(2), "facebook_id" -> x.getString(3))))
    val json = row.toSeq.map(x => x)

    /**
      * code make Http call
      */
    println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
    println(json)
    println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
  }
I event tried to repartition to 1 partition still no luck

Comment: can you let me know what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error, but when I run my code it doesn't print anything, I have modified your function so at the end it print the JSON body

Comment: your print statements in `makeHttpCall ` will not be logged into your console. `makeHttpCall ` method is exectuted in the worker nodes whose stdout is not redirected to your console.

Comment: is there any way I can return the JSON, I need to some stuff before calling the HTTP request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170244/discussion-between-rogue-one-and-am1rr3za).

Comment: one thing that I have noticed your solution generates an array of array of JSON object instead of just array of JSON objects, do you have any fix for that?

Comment: Do you have the python equivalent of this code?