# How to send a bunch of dataframe records to an API using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, batch-processing

How to batch send dataframe tuples to an API.

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': '*/*'
}

data = {"some_key": "some_value", "another_key": "another_value" }
r = requests.post('https://api.somewhere/batch', params={}, headers=headers, json=data)
```

If the JSON payload is from a DataFrame in PySpark, how can I take advantage of Spark to batch process this currently single threaded approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Send DataFrame as body of HTTP Post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139164/spark-send-dataframe-as-body-of-http-post-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a dataframe to JSON:

```py
def batch_json(row):
    # Anything you want to process with every row/partition
    r = requests.post('https://api.somewhere/batch', params={}, headers=headers, json=row)
    print(r.status_code)

df.toJSON().foreach(batch_json)

# OR 
# "batch_json" cannot be used as it is, you will have to change it according to your need

df.toJSON().foreachPartition(batch_json)
```

Quick testing code:

```
def batch(row):
    print(row)

df.toJSON().foreach(batch)
```